# Is $0$ the only number which satisfies $-\epsilon <a< \epsilon$, $\forall \epsilon >0$?

Tags: inequality

The question I am trying to answer is:

Can you find more than one number $a$ which satisfies

(a)$-\epsilon <a< \epsilon$, $\forall \epsilon >0$;

(b)$|a|<\epsilon$, $\forall \epsilon>0$ (Argue by contradiction. If $a\neq 0$, try $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}|a|$).

Source: Numbers and Functions by R. P. Burn. Chapter:2 Question: 65

---

Working:

(a) Since $a$ has to be less than every positive $\epsilon$, the only number which can satisfy this condition is $0$. Taking any other number would result in some value of $a$ not satisfying the inequality at $a=\epsilon$.

**Edit (a)**: By choosing an arbitrarily 'small' $\epsilon$ we get $-\epsilon$ getting arbitrarily close to $a$ from the negative side and $\epsilon$ getting arbitrarily close to $a$ from the positive side. It makes intuitive sense then that the only number for which $-\epsilon<a<\epsilon$ holds true is $a=0$.

(b) $-\epsilon <a<\epsilon \Leftrightarrow |a|<\epsilon$, so the same holds $\forall \epsilon >0$.

(Contradiction argument: for $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}|a|$ and $a\neq 0$, we would have $|a|<\frac{1}{2}|a| \Rightarrow 1<\frac{1}{2}$, which is not true.)

Doesn't the above also suggest that when $|a-b|<\epsilon, \forall \epsilon >0$, $a=b$?

Comment: You're missing quantors for $\epsilon$. I'm assuming you're looking for an $a$ such that **for any** $\epsilon>0$ ($\forall\epsilon>0$) it is true that $-\epsilon < a < \epsilon$. In this case what you write is true, this implies $a=0$.

Comment: @Florian Yes, I forgot to add that. Will edit.

Comment: To answer your last question: it doesn't just suggest it; it requires it. Notice that you have proven that $a-b=0$.

Comment: You can even drop the factor $\frac12$. Just taking $\epsilon=|a|$ gives $-|a|<a<|a|$. Since $|a|\in\{a,-a\}$, this means $a<a$ (either on the left or on the right side). This is obviously wrong. And (b) gives $|a|<|a|$.

Comment: "Since a has to be less than every positive ϵ, the only number which can satisfy this condition is 0. Taking any other number would result in some value of a not satisfying the inequality at a=ϵ."  This is correct but on style I do not like it.  The first sentence is simply a restatement of what you are trying to  prove so it sounds like your argument is circular.  The second sentence isn't quite true.  If a < 0 then you can not ever take a=ϵ so it may be possible that there is a negative a where this is true.  Also it isn't quite clear what and why you are arguing.

Comment: @fleablood While continuing my study your comment kept coming into my memory and I decided to put a little edit into the question. Thanks for nudging me towards 'cleaning up' my statements.

Comment: As to your final question, the answer is yes, since $a-b$ now has to be $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the part (b), just notice the equivalence

$$-\epsilon<a<\epsilon\iff|a|<\epsilon.$$

To address the initial uniquenes question directly, let us assume that there are two numbers $a\ne b$ such that

$$\forall \epsilon>0,-\epsilon<a,b<\epsilon.$$

But by hypothesis $\eta:=|a-b|$ is a positive number, and $|a-b|<|a|+|b|<2\epsilon$, so that all $\epsilon$ such that $0<\epsilon\le\eta/2$ create a contradiction.

Comment: The essence of your proof is that we assume two unequal numbers satisfy the condition. Then we show that this leads to a contradiction and so our assumption must be incorrect (this being the part where we use $\epsilon=|a-b|$). Hence $a=b$ is the only alternative. The second sentence in your answer is very compact and I'm just trying to put it into words to see if I understand it correctly. Many thanks for the further clarification.

Comment: @shredalert: this approach has a peculiarity: it is not constructive, in the sense that it doesn't provide the value of $a$, only proving that it is unique.

Comment: Isn't this an advantage, however? We are trying to find if any non-zero number satisfies the condition, and our proof doesn't require knowing the value of $a$.

Comment: @shredalert: I said peculiarity, I didn't say disadvantage :)

Comment: My apologies. :p

Answer (score 1):

If $a$ has to be a real number, then that is correct.

But just for fun, would this hold in other models of the usual axioms for the real numbers?

Turns out that for other fun models such as [non-standard analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_analysis) the answer is still **YES**.

Indeed, the usual axiomatizations of the reals such as [Tarski's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski's_axiomatization_of_the_reals) constrain their models to be linearly ordered fields, where every number other than zero is either positive or has a positive opposite.

Since the hypothesis requires than $-\epsilon < a < \epsilon$ for every $\epsilon$, and in particular $a < b$ implies $a \neq b$, we have that only the element zero satisfies this property.